# Получение массива данных socket.io

Tags: reactjs, websocket, socket.io

нужно вывести данные компаний их цену на рынке название и тд в реальном времени бекент уже написан
пример: server.js

```
`'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const io = require('socket.io');
const cors = require('cors');

const FETCH_INTERVAL = 5000;
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

const tickers = [
  'AAPL', // Apple
  'GOOGL', // Alphabet
  'MSFT', // Microsoft
  'AMZN', // Amazon
  'FB', // Facebook
  'TSLA', // Tesla
];

function randomValue(min = 0, max = 1, precision = 0) {
  const random = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  return random.toFixed(precision);
}

function utcDate() {
  const now = new Date();
  return new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(), now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
}

function getQuotes(socket) {

  const quotes = tickers.map(ticker => ({
    ticker,
    exchange: 'NASDAQ',
    price: randomValue(100, 300, 2),
    change: randomValue(0, 200, 2),
    change_percent: randomValue(0, 1, 2),
    dividend: randomValue(0, 1, 2),
    yield: randomValue(0, 2, 2),
    last_trade_time: utcDate(),
  }));

  socket.emit('ticker', quotes);
}

function trackTickers(socket) {
  // run the first time immediately
  getQuotes(socket);

  // every N seconds
  const timer = setInterval(function () {
    getQuotes(socket);
  }, FETCH_INTERVAL);

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
  });
}

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
const server = http.createServer(app);

const socketServer = io(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  }
});

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    message: "Hello FullStack appendix"
  })
})

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

socketServer.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('start', () => {
    trackTickers(socket);
  });
});

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Streaming service is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
}); 
`
```

index.html:

```
`<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
        Quote Stream
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:4000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    'use strict';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');
        socket.emit('start');
        socket.on('ticker', function (response) {
            const res = Array.isArray(response) ? response : [response];
            const json = res.map(item => JSON.stringify(item)).join('\n');
            const data = $(`<pre>${json}</pre><hr />`);
            $('#quotes').append(data);
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 100);
            $(data).show('slide', { direction: 'up' }, 300);
            $(data).effect('highlight', {}, 1500);
        });
    });
</script>

<body>
    <div id="quotes"></div>
</body>

</html>`
```

мой код:

```
`import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import axios from 'axios';

const socket = io();

function App() {
  const [clientUsers, setClientUsers] = useState([])
  const socket = io()

  socket.on('sid', users => {
    setClientUsers(users)
  })

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{clientUsers}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;`
```

Comment: а что не получается сделать или что работает не так?

Comment: для меня в новинку websocket до этого http пользовался fetch запросами получал данные и размещал на свою страничку , socket io не поддерживает "fetch запрос" это не точно .Теперь вопрос как получить данные сервера и разместить их файле app

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что нужно рабочий пример перенести в `App` файл на React?

Comment: так у socket io  есть пример. в чем проблема переделать под свои нужды https://socket.io/how-to/use-with-react-hooks

Comment: я нашёл решение, на форум попробовал написать проверить какой тут фидбек в новинку.